# How do you open pgp-encrypted documents from nautilus?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, seahorse, pgp

Seahorse (gnome PGP/GPG frontend) integration is not working in 11.10. In 11.04 you could open pgp-encrypted documents from nautilus by dbclking and entering the pgp passphrase when prompted. 11.10 doesn't try to open it, even if seahorse is installed, and if you use "Open with other application" and then do "Find applications online", it will recommend **KGpg**.

Answer (score 1):

The seahorse-plugins package that provides the nautilus integration that you're talking about has been removed from 11.10. There is a bug report here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/seahorse-plugins/+bug/796752/ To summarise: it seems related to the Gnome 3 upgrade, since the last seahorse-plugins package appears to be for Gnome 2.30.

Answer (score 1):

Now if you need to decrypt and don't know how to do without the Gnome support it would be very easy from command line :

```
sudo apt-get install pgpgpg
pgp myfile
```

Then it will ask your pass-phrase  and decrypt your file in the same directory.